# How do other nodes handle the accounts of a deleted node?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, nodes, peers

In Ethereum Blockchain, the accounts created on one node stay with it and are not replicated into other nodes.

If that node is deleted and hence is not a part of that network, then what happen to the accounts local to it? Are these accounts removed from the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you are having some serious misunderstandings about some fundamental ideas regarding the blockchain technology.

You only store the private key of an account under your node keystore folder, the account states and transactions are all stored in the blockchain, which is stored in every (full) nodes. You need the private key to send out transactions from the account, so if you delete the "account" from your local node, which means you delete the private key stored with your local node, and if you do not have the private key backed up somewhere, it means you will not be able to send transactions (ie. spend ethers) from the account anymore.

The account itself, which basically means the account states (ie. ether balances and things) and related transaction records, are still stored in the blockchain itself, and cannot be deleted at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where do you think is a good place to store all the keystore files from different nodes? Do we get have software that solves this purpose? I'll be having more than 1000 accounts.

Comment: There is something called HD wallet which basically let you generate (practically) an infinite number of private keys from one single master key, which can be recorded as 12 mnemonic seed phrases that you can write down on a paper and store it somewhere safe.

Comment: If you really need to store all those different keystore files, then the only thing I can think of is some USB flashdrives and then you can lock them up in a safe. And then maybe store the passwords to those keystore files in some other USB flashdrives and lock them up in a different safe.

Comment: Albeit I'm not too sure why you want to store so many different keystore files from different nodes? If you can explain your situation a bit more, maybe I can be of more help. I can't really think of a scenario where you need to run so many different full nodes and each with their own different accounts under their keystore folders.

Answer (score 1):

The accounts are not stored in the nodes. Only the keys to the accounts are stored in the nodes. If you delete a node, only the keys are deleted. You can still send ether to the account. If you have backed up the keystore folder. You can copy this folder and to another working node to use the account.

It would be easy to understand this way, nodes store your password for the account. (This explanation may be too surfacial)